# Grub is not appearing after installing Ubuntu in entire harddisk

Tags: grub2, ssd

I'm using DELL computer. I've a installed a Ubuntu in a SSD by **formatting entire harddisk** in the installation menu of ubuntu means now there is only 1 operating system in SSD right now.[you can see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNdb2.jpg)

After the installation it says you have to restart the PC after removing the USB.

Then **Grub is not appearing** and there is an error which is being showing **"No operating System is found. Press any key to repeat the boot sequence "**
[You may see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNRig.jpg)

But when I enject the usb again and then I open the PC second time then **grub is appearing** [you may see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wISqU.jpg) , but Ubuntu is still not installed at that time also.

and it show again same thing **" Try or Install Ubuntu "** , but I've already installed and I did this 7 times.

When I go to the option of  **" Try & install "** so in the space option/ Storage option shows that 128 GB has assigned to Ubuntu.[you may see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv69B.jpg)

Need suggestions, your graceful answers will be helpful to me.

Comment: Start Gparted and check whether the `bootable` flag is set on the root partition.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? How you boot install media is then how it installs & then system must be set to boot in that mode. Most systems now are UEFI since Microsoft required UEFI with gpt partitioning since 2012. Post this in question above: `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid` But it looks like you installed ISO to SSD? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview